# Create related nodes to specific node

Tags: nodes

I am using Drupal 7.

In one of my requirements i need to create related node to specific node.

For ex. I have created a node of content type "article". For particular node of "article" node

say nid:9 then i would like to add related node to this node.

So when i view nid:9 at that time it should also display related nodes, and also when i view the newly created node, at that time nid:9 should be displayed in related node display

So both nodes should be displayed vice versa in each others detail view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a node reference field. See:

[image]

Comment: Greta, if you have used this module then node reference provide any kind of API function to fetch referenced nodes. I mean if i visit node 45 and node reference is node 47 then when i visit any of the node, respective refereed nodes should be displayed

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a few modules that relate two (or more) nodes together, [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) and [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) are both popular.

I'd probably recommend the Entity Reference module as that comes with a couple of field formatters that display the referenced entity. If you used the Relation module you'd probably have to build a fairly complex view with contextual filters and relationships - [this screencast series](http://nodeone.se/en/learn-the-relation-module) should help with that.